# Call function from jar in MainActivity

Tags: android, jar

First time I'm trying to make my own .jar file. It works, but now I want to give feedback to the MainActivity. So I want to call a function 'receiveSerial()' in the MainActivity.

So the MainActivity must always implement the function 'receiveSerial()' when including my .jar.

**.jar file (part of the) code:**

```
package com.hoeks.ma.bluetooth;

import java.util.Set;

import ...

public class Blauwe{
    ..
    private Activity ma;

    public Blauwe(Activity m){
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        ma = (Activity)m;
    }

    ..

    public void sendSerial(String s) {
        ma.receiveSerial(s);   // This line give Eclipse error "Add cast to ma" 
                               // When I add the cast it is not working
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
import com.hoeks.ma.bluetooth.Blauwe;
....

public void receiveSerial(String s) {
    javascr.setSerial(s);
}
```

Note: I do not post the whole code because the code is a big mess right now, its not good for the readability.

Comment: for that you must have to create the interface/extract class in your jar and after extract or implement it in your main activity.

OtherWise create a instance of that class(which is in jar) and get the method using instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create `interface`

```
public interface ReceiveSerialCallback{
    public void receiveSerial(String s);
}
```

2) add `interface` implementation in `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity implements ReceiveSerialCallback{

    ...
    public void receiveSerial(String s) {
        // serial received
    }
}
```

3) update `Blauwe` class

```
private ReceiveSerialCallback callback;

... 
public void setReceiveSerialCallback(ReceiveSerialCallback callback) {
     this.callback = callback;
}
...
public void sendSerial(String s) {
    callback.receiveSerial(s);
}
```

4) set `inteface` callback object to `Blauwe` class in `MainActivity`

```
Blauwe b = new Blauwe();
b.setReceiveSerialCallback(this);
```

Comment: Yes perfect explanation. Works perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast because `receiveSerial(String)` is not a method of `Activity`, but `MainActivity`. I would create an `interface` (with method sendSerial) that `MainActivity` should implement, and save a reference of this interface in Blauwe class, instead of an Activity instance.